# Cannot boot, install Freya

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install the latest elementary OS Freya on my old laptop - Acer Ferrari WLMI4005.

Doesn't boot - in BIOS I have boot from CD.

I see only black screen with elementary OS logo and do nothing.

On the laptop Mint install is working.

Any ideas? 
Thank you

Comment: Press the ESC key while on the elementary logo

Comment: Added as answer .Mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key while on the elementary OS logo. This should work on some computers